# Autonomous homomorphic encryption

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

So, my understanding of homomorphic encryption is that Alice has a private key and an algorithm, gives an encrypted copy of the algorithm to Bob, Bob runs the algorithm without understanding it, and gives the encrypted result back to Alice, who decrypts the result with her private key.

There's a variant of this concept that interests me.  Consider the following scenario.  Alice has a proprietary algorithm.  Bob is interested in using the algorithm, but is frequently out of network access or something, and doesn't want to have to communicate back with Alice for every evaluation.  Alice uses a newfangled method called (e.g.) Autonomous Homomorphic Encryption to encrypt her algorithm, and gives it to Bob.  Bob runs the algorithm, unable to understand it, but when he gives inputs to the algorithm, it can (at its own discretion) output plaintext results.

Has any significant work been done on such an encryption mechanism?  Does it have a name?  Has it been proven possible or impossible?

Comment: Give me the algorithm, then I can try some standard vectors to decide the algorithm.

Comment: Does the encrypted program take as input "plaintexts" and output "plaintexts"? If so, this sounds quite similar to program obfuscation.

Comment: @kelalaka You mean, try to reverse engineer the algorithm based on the inputs vs outputs?  That'd work for some algorithms, but I suspect others would be intractable.  For instance, I'd be pretty surprised if you could reverse engineer SHA256 solely from inputs and outputs.

Comment: @Mark Eh, I suppose it's technically a form of program obfuscation, yeah - it's a pretty advanced form of it, though, and would probably involve harder provable limits on what an attacker could do or infer.  For instance, you might require the property that flipping a single bit of instructions or state data would completely scramble the whole program and subsequent state, similar to guarantees of integrity provided by some other cryptographic methods.  Do you know if there has been specific work done in cryptographic program obfuscation?

Comment: "gives an encrypted copy of the algorithm to Bob" uh, maybe this is me misunderstanding homomorphic encryption, but we generally encrypt a message, or in this case probably better referred to as a value. Encrypting an algorithm doesn't make no sense to me.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes This can be done (I believe it is the idea underlying circuit-private FHE --- encrypt both the circuit and the input, and evaluate the function by using a universal circuit. I'm sure they do smarter stuff than this for efficiency reasons though), but the issue with applying this here is that the output will be a ciphertext, not plaintext.

Comment: So in particular, let $\langle C\rangle$ be some encoding of the circuit, and then homomorphically evaluate $U(\langle C\rangle, x)$ on ciphertexts $c_{\langle C\rangle}, c_{x}$ to get a ciphertext $c_{U(\langle C\rangle, x)} = c_{C(x)}$, where $U$ is a "universal circuit".

Comment: Yes, It can be done, circuit privacy, there was an article by Gentry e al. about obfuscation  but as @Mark said the problem is the output. Also, the circuits are far more practicable.